# Issue with dependencies in gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am new to android and want to create a basic map application in android studio.

The emulator is loading the map but it is grayed out with just Google logo at the left bottom.

Link to emulator's image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJZwc.jpg

The build.gradle file is showing red underline on following line.

Link to gradle file https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhH7Q.jpg

After googling about the Grayed out issue I found that there is some issue in build.gradle file.

Hence I checked various solutions on stackoverflow and added the three lines (commented now) in build.gradle file.

As none of the solutions given on stack overflow solved the issue hence posting this as a new question.

Android Studio Version: 3.2.1

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

//Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.krishnaji.mapfun"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  //  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  //  implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

}
```

//MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is 
ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker 
in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
 Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome to Maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Want to see Sydney marked in the map shown on Emulator.
PS: I can see the Toast Welcome to Maps but the map is grayed out